# how to create a widget to select the image of a product

Tags: thumbnail

I have a widget that selects the product but it returns the sku and the id of the product, and what I need is the image or a thumbail.

any idea what block I call because for this I make the call to the block

```
        <parameter name="id_path" xsi:type="block" visible="true" required="true" sort_order="10">
            <label translate="true">Product</label>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser">
                <data>
                    <item name="button" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="open" xsi:type="string">Seleccionar Producto...</item>
                    </item>
                </data>
            </block>
        </parameter>
```

the above code returns this in the frontend

[image]

I would appreciate some help

Answer (score 0):

This may help you regarding this :

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-widget/#step-1-declare-widget-widgetxml

https://www.toptal.com/magento/custom-widgets-in-magento-2